# Is there a device that allows watching international internet TV on my LCD TV?

Tags: tv, htpc, tuner-card, home-theater

Is there a Home Theatre device that will allow watching international interent TV on my LDC TV?   I saw one once but I am not able to find it.

I am NOT talking about a Slingbox here.

Something like [WWitv.com](http://wwitv.com/)  or [TV.exe](http://www.tvexe.com/) , but made as a set-top box for the livingroom.

Answer (score 1):

the **[FitPC2](http://www.compulab.co.il/fitpc2/html/fitpc2-datasheet.htm)** might suit your needs:

[image]

```
Full-featured PC, tiny and power saving
Intel Atom Z530 CPU @ 1.6 GHz
Intel US15W chipset
1GB DDR2
160GB SATA harddisk, easily upgradeable
DVI Digital display interface, up to 1920x1080
HD Audio, line-out 2.0 / mic in / line-in
1000Mb/s Ethernet port
802.11g WiFi
Six USB 2.0 ports
miniSD and mini PCI Express sockets
IR receiver
Phoenix BIOS
Single 12V supply, 6W, fanless operation
Dimensions - 115 x 101 x 27mm
Runs Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7 and Linux
Also available as SBC without enclosure
```

[$380 at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BV353U)

or the **Acer Revo**, similar specification, better graphics (nVidia ION), pricing starts at [$199](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002O3W44Q) but larger in size and more power-consuming.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

... Looking at wwitv.com, it looks pretty cool - You could always get an ION / ATOM powered small form factor computer and link it up to your tv - use a wireless keyboard and mouse then actually visit those sites.

Also gives you a lot of flexibility for the future (thinking webcam, instant messenger etc.)

This is personally, what I would do.